# How to Make the DS18B20 Temperature Probes Plug into a Bread Board Easier

Tags: breadboard, ds18b20

I use a RPi with waterproof DS18B20 temperature probes to measure the temperature of my homebrew. Every time I brew a batch I must sanitize the probe and insert them through the airlock into the brew, and then connect the three wires into my bread board. I've done this so much that the novelty has worn off and this is just frustrating. I am liable to have 4 sets of DS18B20 probes measuring 4 batches of beer. When I disconnect or reconnect one probe, it is easy to knock out another probe.

I am thinking about jumper wires and how easy and stable they are to plug into a breadboard. Would it be possible to plug a wire from the DS18B20 into the female end of a male to female jumper wire, and permanently set it?

Or, what else can be done to minimize my problem?

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem like yours and I had to attach the female ends of the jumper wires to the DS18B20 sensor like this:

[image: DS18B20]

I hope it helps.

P.D. Here is a video on how to make headers (Its pretty much the same for male pins)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEPdB-W3-Tc

Comment: Should I purchase something like this? http://www.pololu.com/product/1013

Comment: Hm; on the other hand, would you link me to where you purchased your headers? Could I get a 12inch male-to-male jumper cable, plug it in the female side in your picture, and plug the other end into a breadboard?  This would extend the size of my DS18B20 another foot.

Comment: On your first comment, the answer is no, since that header is to mount on a PCB not directly on cable, to be honest with you what I did is to disassemble a female jumper wire and use the parts. But those can be purchased: 
http://www.ebay.com/itm/100Pcs-2P-Dupont-Jumper-Wire-Cable-Housing-Female-Pin-Connector-2-54mm-Pitch-HM-/400629541782?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d4761ab96

and

http://www.ebay.com/itm/150Pcs-Female-Pin-Connector-Terminal-2-54mm-Pitch-for-Dupont-Jumper-Wire-Cable-/281246036769?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_2&hash=item417b91f321